# How can I show Id details which i stored in a array?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I save some id in a array using PHP *implode* method. I showed that array value using *explode* method. But I want to show that Id details. Ex: *Title, Image* . How can i do that?

here is store code from controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title'=>'required',
        'image'=>'required',
        'description',
        'available'=>'required',
        'buy'=>'required',
        'account',
        'receive',
    ]);
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('funds'), $new_name);
    $form_data = array(
        'title'=>$request->title,
        'image'=>$new_name,
        'description'=>$request->description,
        'available'=>$request->available,
        'buy'=>$request->buy,
        'buyrate'=>$request->buyrate,
        'sellrate'=>$request->sellrate,
        'account'=>$request->account,
        'receive'=>implode(',', (array)($request->receive)),
    );

    Fund::create($form_data);

    return redirect('/admin/fund');
}
```

Here is, What i send to the index using route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
$funds = DB::table('funds')->get();
$receive=[];
foreach($funds as $fund){
    $receive = explode(",",$fund->receive);
}
return view('frontend.exchangePage.exchange',['funds'=>$funds,'receive'=>$receive]);});
```

Here is the Index what i show from the array:

```
<div class="" style="{{--height: 200px; overflow: auto;--}}">
 @foreach($receive as $r)
   <a href="/multi" class="list-group-item">
      <p>
        <img src="" width="32px" height="32px"> {{  $r }}
          <span class="pull-right text text-muted hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="font-size:11px;">
             <small>Reserve: 1170580 BDT<br>Exchange rate: 1 BDT = 0.98 BDT</small>
          </span>
      </p>
   </a>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: @foreach($receive as $receive)  you cannot use the same variable name for iteration, it will overwrite the previous value

Comment: yes i try this :
@foreach ($receive as $r) 
and still it gives me just the array value

Comment: @optinix `Try json_encode()` and echo the `$r`, what you are getting, you will get the issue.

Comment: $r will give you the array value only because it is the array elements that you are iterating over. What do you want to achieve? DO you want some model instance from that id?

Comment: @AhmedShefeer yes i want model details from that id.

Comment: how you want to display the data here ?

Comment: @AmitSharma i'm storing fund id in that array and i want to show that id's everything like: title, image, charges data on my index page.

Comment: you can use foreach for that. if you need to display the data in funds array. 
like @foreach($funds as $f)
   
 @endforeach

Comment: @AmitSharma Let me clear you. i'm storing a fund with id, title, image and receive[] (array). in that array i'm storing some funds id. In index page. i have two option, one is Send funds, here is shows funds id and details and another is Receive funds. on receive funds i want to show that array value which is funds id and from that funds id, i want to show all data from funds. how to do that?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just written this simple line on my code and it works.

```
@php $receives = \App\Fund::whereIn('id', $receive)->get(); @endphp
```